# Python Sublists Remove Method

Tags: python, methods, sublist

I have the following list of suubjects and grades I have named "gradebook"

[gradebook list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqffR.png)

I am attempting to remove the value 85 from the sublist [poetry, 85]
[sublist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRi3T.png)

I can remove the sublist itself with the following syntax

```
gradebook.remove(["poetry", 85])
```

I can't seem to remove the 85

I have tried to use the following syntax

```
gradebook.remove([85])
```

but I get the following error

> ```
> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File "script.py", line 15, in
> > <module>
> >     gradebook.remove([85])  ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
> ```

I have also tried to use the following

```
gradebook.remove([2][1])
```

Instead I get the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "script.py", line 15, in
>
> gradebook.remove([2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqffR.png))  IndexError: list index out of range

I don't know if it is possible to, but how can I remove that item (85) in the sublist?

Comment: `gradebook[index].remove(85)`. Lists don't do anything with elements, you have to fetch the element and operate on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with multi-dimensional data you need to navigate to the item you want to operate on before submethods will work as you expect. Your data is a list *of lists*, so you need to let the program know you want to operate on a specific list within your data. Your data is below.

```py
gradebook = [[“physics”, 98], [“calculus”, 97], [“poetry”, 85], [“history”, 88]]
```

Navigate to the item of index `2` so the returned value is the list `["poetry", 85]`. Then you can operate on this list individually by calling the `.remove(85)` method.

```py
# Define gradeboook
gradebook = [[“physics”, 98], [“calculus”, 97], [“poetry”, 85], [“history”, 88]]
# Get the index of your list
index = gradebook.index(["poetry", 85])
# Navigate and remove 85
gradebook[index].remove(85)
```

You can also do the last two steps with one line:

```py
gradebook[gradebook.index(["poetry", 85])].remove(85)
```

This works because the item returned when you call `gradebook[gradebook.index(["poetry", 85])]` is the list `["poetry", 85]` itself. Once you call it in this way you can modify it with `remove()`, as you please.

Answer (score -1):

So index starts at 0 for lists so you could just do del gradebook[1]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).